# InotifyPropertychange event of underlying object of a list should not be fired

Tags: c#, list, inotifypropertychanged

I have a object whose data members have INotifypropertychange event implemented.I want to maintain a list of objects separately where I do not want to reflect the property change.How can I do it

Comment: Simply do not attach any handlers to their PropertyChanged events. Otherwise you'd need to rewrite (alter their code to remove the noifictions) or wrap the items.

Comment: Can you please elaborate ,how this could be done? Since I also need INotify Property change which I handle with a help of Observable Collection. But I also need to keep a back up list where changes dont get reflected.

Comment: Sorry, now I don't fully grasp what you want to achieve. If you have "Item" that is INPC and that implements INPC correctly, and if you put it into the ObsCollection, then the ObsColl will attach to the Items' PropertyChanged events, and upon any change to the Item's props, the Item will raise notification and the ObsColl will hear it. You cannot prevent that unless you change how the item is implemented or unless you change the ObsCollection to a dumb `List<T>` or other.

Comment: If a class is written to handle events, it will do so. If a class is written to raise notifications, it will do so. If you dont want such behaviour, use different classes that do what you want.

Comment: Well I want a list out of my observable collection which do not raise any INPC.Is that possible?

Comment: ObsColl raises only its own notifications and you can escape from that by using plain `List<>` or Array. If you want to also prevent INPC events, then there's no way, because it is the ITEMS that raise INPC notifications, not the collection it self. You'd have to replace the ITEMS with something different, like wrapping each item with some proxy objects.. give me a sec

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the function GetDeepCopy() to get your object which would not raise INPC.

public class ValidationModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

```
    private string _validationName;

    public string validationName
    {
        get { return _validationName; }
        set { _validationName = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ValidationName"); }

    }



    public ValidationModel GetDeepCopy()
    {
        var model = new ValidationModel();

        model.validationName = validationName;

        return model;

    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyname)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyname));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrapping/proxying example:

```
class MyItem : INPC
{
    public string Name { get { ... } set { this.name = value; raisePropChanged("Name") } } ....
}

var item = new MyItem();
collection.Add(item);

item.Name = "John"; // notifies whoever listens on collection



class MyItemWrapper
{
    private MyItem theBrain;

    public string Name { get{return theBrain.Name;} set{theBrain.Name = value;}}
}

var item = new MyItem();
var wrapped = new MyItemWrapper { theBrain = item };

collectionOne.Add(item);
collectionTwo.Add(wrapped);

item.Name = "John";
// notifies whoever listens on collectionOne
// but whoever listens on collectionTwo will not get any notification
// since "wrapper" does not notify about anything.
// however, since wrapper forwards everything to 'brain':

var name = wrapped.Name; // == "John"
```

Comment: Thx. But I got a better way to do it by maintaining a deep copy.